# can not send multiple mail using while loop in php

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email for multiple addresses that are retrieved from db

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry9)) {
    $email=$row["email"];
    $subject = "Testing";
    $headers = "From: test@gmail.com \r\n";
    $message='New Event Registered';
    mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);        
}
```

In this given like `$email="nandha181@gmail.com"` is working properly but `email` from `database` is not working .I am also checking the email from the `database` query works correctly.

Comment: **Note*** that `mysql` is deprecated and removed as of PHP7 instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Please read this `example` : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example

Comment: Are you working on localhost, might be possible that PHP mail function is not ON there. Try using SMTP

Comment: `trim()` your database email.

Comment: You did some debugging? Are there any rows being retrieved from database? $row["email"] have a valid e-mail? Try using var_dump($row["email"]); to confirm these.

Comment: Check your query stored in `$qry9`

Comment: i am using trim function. Mail works properlyly.. Thank You  Frayne Konok sir, and also thanks for all

Comment: Tirth is close: base your code on [this example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).